# How to cast a class according to a generic type?

Tags: java, class, generics, casting, type-conversion

I am writing automation with Java and Selenium.
I would like to create a generic method that calls a method that exists in different child pages (classes) according to a generic type parameter.

- all pages inherit from BasePage.
- each page has a different implementation of a method called xxx()
- the generic method will be placed in a helper class (I guess)

Something like this:

```
 public <T> BasePage doSomething(Class<T> pageType)
{
//Navigate to the page and gets the page
BasePage page = navigate....

//call the method according to the received class
page.xxx()
}
```

How can I case the page to the correct type and call its method?

Comment: If the method exists across all page classes and all base classes are derived from `BaseClass`, then you can create it's abstract method in it's superclass. Then you can cast to `BasePage`, if you have an object. Then you can call the method like this: `page.xxx()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple improvements here, one of which is to make `T` extend `BaseClass` in your method like this:

```java
public <T extends BasePage> T doSomething(Class<T> pageClass) {
    // nav to page
    T page = ...

    // call to xxx
    page.xxx();

    // ...somehow return page
    return page;
}
```

This will make the return type of the function more specific in the places you use it. Furthermore, you will not need to cast anything here, as you already have 'something more specific than `BasePage`'.
Then create an abstract method in `BasePage`:

```java
abstract class BasePage {
    ...
    // has to be implemented in the child classes.
    public abstract whatever xxx(...)
}
```